# Problem with setVisible(boolean)

Tags: java, swing, visibility

I have a `JFrame` with some component on it. I want that the frame disappears when i click on a special button for example `exit button`.

I wrote this code in exit button

```
this.setvisible(false);
```

but it only hides the component on it and frame doesn't disappear.

What can I do that when I click on `exit button` the frame disappears?

Comment: Please show us the relevant code. I suppose  `this` refers to the JButton and not to the JFrame.

Comment: well, setvisible doesn't exit the program.

Comment: @experimentX - You can have multiple JFrames in an application and some of them can be hidden for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your call `this.setVisible(false)`, `this` probably refers to the button and not the frame.

You need to call setVisible() on the Frame not the Button.

Also make sure you are calling dispose() on the frame to clean up all resources.

Additionally you should also use

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

during creation of the frame, to make sure the windows is properly closed and disposed when the user clicks the "standard" close button in the upper right corner (on Windows).

This tutorial might also help you understand what's going on better:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of a button that hides the frame:

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
final JButton hideButton = new JButton("hide frame");
frame.add(hideButton);
hideButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      frame.setVisible(false);
   }

});

frame.setVisible(true);
frame.pack();
```

Answer (score 0):

call it on JFrame object.
example:
`// when exit is pressed`

`fr.setVisible(false); // fr is a reference to object of type JFrame`         `